# CSS Display:Inline Block issue

Tags: html, css

So I am not sure what am I doing wrong here, basically I am using this HTML:

```
<p class="cl">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="1">1</p>
<p class="cl price">someth</p>
<p class="cl">
    <input type="radio" name="number" value="2">2</p>
<p class="cl price">other</p>
```

and this CSS:

```
.price
{
  float: right;
}
.cl
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

Basically what is happening is that I want 1 thing in front of the other, and that is not happening, however if I put a div in the middle of the theoretic lines they will work as intended.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/to20Lr1g/)

Comment: Have you tried using `z-index`?

Comment: What do you mean by ' 1 thing in front of the other'?

Comment: You need to set the container with an absolute position and the p classes as relative for it to work correctly.

Comment: @alirezasafian 1 want a radio with the price in front of it

Comment: @Harry I am using it because I want to have the price aligned to the right of the container

Comment: @João Ferreira Can you post an image which is shown your desire situation?

Comment: @JoãoFerreira: Did that help? If not, please post an image of the required output like mentioned in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you dont set lines. If you male a div per line it would work:

```
<div class="price-line">
    <p class="cl">
        <input type="radio" name="number" value="1">1</p>
    <p class="cl price">someth</p>
<div>
<div class="price-line">
    <p class="cl">
        <input type="radio" name="number" value="2">2</p>
    <p class="cl price">other</p>
<div>
```

And for the ces still the same:

```
.price{
    float: right;
}
.cl{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin: 5px;
};
```

Have a Nice Day ;)
Ps: you can use a div or anything else that takes 100% of the width I think ;)